# style specific port in jointjs

Tags: javascript, css, jointjs

**1)** I'm using JointJS diagramming lib. I want to change the css of a particular `inPort` when using `joint.shapes.devs`.

For linking sourcePort to the target I'm using

`source: { id: source.id, selector: source.getPortSelector(sourcePort)}`

It's giving me accurate source port, but how to apply css on this particular port after knowing it as my source connector? Is there a way?

**2)** Can we fit/wrap the label automatically inside the element if its width is longer than the element-width? I'm using `joint.shapes.devs.Atomic` element(s).

I came across `foreignobject` but don't know how to use it? 
Can anyone throw some light on it?

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
myShape.attr('[port="a"]/fill', 'blue')
```

where the first part of the first argument before slash is a CSS selector pointing to the port circle SVG element, the second part is an SVG attribute to be set on that element and the second argument is a value to be set for that attribute. An alternative syntax for doing the same thing would be:

```
myShape.attr({ '[port="a"]': { fill: 'blue' } })
```

See the `attr()` method reference for details: http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:attr.

2) The `joint.shapes.devs.Atomic` shape does not automatically do that. You would have to create your own shape and do it there either via `foreighObject` or programmatically in JavaScript. As a reference for using `foreignObject`, please see the `joint.shapes.basic.TextBlock` shape that is defined in this file: https://github.com/DavidDurman/joint/blob/master/plugins/joint.shapes.basic.js.

Comment: 1) Perfectly answered! 2) I didn't get how to wrap text in `joint.shapes.devs`? Didn't even find an example to use `foreignObject` to wrap text. Can you please help me on that.